# Where do I find traffic sources for same-domain traffic?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

I have two different Google Analytics accounts set up.  One that is used everywhere on `example.com`, and another that is used only within the `example.com/blog` path.  I'm trying to figure out where within my `example.com` GA account I can track users who are navigating from the `/blog` GA account.

I tried looking under Traffic Sources > Referring Sites, then filtering by `example.com`.  This does show as a source there, but when I clicked on it to view referral paths for that source, none of the referral paths were for `/blog`; instead, they were all just other pages within the same domain (and thus the same GA account).

Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that you're going to get exactly what you want, because it's on the same domain, if you were using blog.yoursite.com instead of yoursite.com/blog you could use referring sites.

One way that might get you close would be to create an advanced segment that uses a "landing page" that contains "/blog" in the URL string this would limit your reports to only those that entered the site via the blog, then you can create a custom content report and filter out URLs that include "blog" this will give you data about the main site only showing visitors that entered through the blog.

Another option would be to tag each link on your blog to the main site with campaign tracking, I haven't tested this and can't confirm that it won't mess up you're analytics in some fashion so I would test it on a separate profile first.

Neither are 100% what you're looking for but hopefully it at least gave you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the navigation summary. Like the other answer, it's not perfect, but it may be good enough. Go to Content > Site Content > All Pages and search for /blog. Then, in the tabs above the graph switch from Explorer to Navigation Summary. This will show you where people went after /blogs.

The drawback is that you can't get the number of people who went from /blogs to example.com/products unless you manually add the results for /products in the navigation summary.

I'm surprised that Google Analytics doesn't give a way to analyze same-domain traffic that's more granular than the visitor flow.